# Create simple table with multiple columns using tblr

Tags: tables, tabularray, tblr

I created a table that is embedded in a beamer presentation:

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{booktabs} % tables
\usepackage{amsmath} % align, 
\usepackage{siunitx} % units, numbers
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs}

\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}[space]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
    \scriptsize
    \begin{table}
    \captionsetup{font=scriptsize}
        \qquad
        \begin{minipage}{0.342\linewidth}
            \caption{Title}
            \vspace{-1ex}
            \begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z},colspec={@{} l Q[l, mode={math}] @{}},rowsep=1pt}
            A&L\textsubscript{a}=\qty{11}{km}\\
            B&L\textsubscript{b}=\qty{1000}{km}\\
            C&L\textsubscript{c}=\qty{150}{km}\\
            \end{tblr} 
        \end{minipage}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

1. How can I add additional columns? (should be 3 rows x 7 columns)
2. How can I add the column names?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you consider cosulting the [package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf) for `tabularry`? You specify two columns currently, one is text mode, one is math mode. You should describe more specific what kind of additional columns you'd like to add. And why did you tag this question with `multicolumn`?

Comment: the package manual was what I was looking for, thank you. Col 1 = textmode (rownames), col2-8 = mathmode. Row 1 = textmode (colnames), row 2-4 = mathmode

Comment: So, you want 8 columns and 5 rows in total, all cells should be math mode except the topmost row and the leftmost column? Do you care about the sizes (width) of the cells?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how the result should look like, but maybe you want something similiar to this:

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{siunitx} % units, numbers
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}[space]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
    \scriptsize
    \begin{table}
    \captionsetup{font=scriptsize}
        \qquad
        \begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}
            \caption{Title}
            \vspace{-1ex}
            \begin{tblr}{
                colspec={ @{} l *{7}{Q[l, mode={math}]} @{} },
                row{1} = {mode={text}},
                hline{1,Z},
                rowsep=1pt
            }
              & I am in text mode    & & & & & & \\
            A & L_a = \qty{11}{km}   & x & x & x & x & x & x \\
            B & L_b = \qty{1000}{km} & & & & & & \\
            C & L_c = \qty{150}{km}  & & & & & & \\
            \end{tblr} 
        \end{minipage}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

That is, there are 8 columns and 5 rows in total. All cells are in math mode except for the first row and the first column. Note that the table is most likely wider than the width that you stated for the `minipage`.